# Do the following phrases mean the same?

Tags: phrases, expressions

Does "Topics created by Users" equal to "User created topics"?

Comment: They sound the same to me. But in the second I would place a hyphen ; *user-created topics*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they mean the same thing. And yes, as @WS2 mentions in a comment, you will want to add a hyphen: *User-created topics*.